# Cron error while executing

Tags: magento-1.9, cron, error-log

```
Cron error while executing catalogrule_apply_all:

exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction' in /domains/domainsmain/http/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
Stack trace:
#0 /domains/domainsmain/http/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 /domains/domainsmain/http/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#2 /domains/domainsmain/http/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#3 /domains/domainsmain/http/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#4 /domains/domainsmain/http/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('DELETE FROM `ca...', Array)
#5 /domains/domainsmain/http/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(504): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('DELETE FROM `ca...', Array)
#6 /domains/domainsmain/http/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(664): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('DELETE FROM `ca...')
#7 /domains/domainsmain/http/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogRule/Model/Resource/Rule.php(164): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->delete('catalogrule_pro...', Array)
#8 /domains/domainsmain/http/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogRule/Model/Resource/Rule.php(344): Mage_CatalogRule_Model_Resource_Rule->cleanProductData('15')
#9 [internal function]: Mage_CatalogRule_Model_Resource_Rule->updateRuleProductData(Object(Mage_CatalogRule_Model_Rule))
#10 /domains/domainsmain/http/lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php(466): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#11 /domains/domainsmain/http/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogRule/Model/Rule.php(317): Varien_Data_Collection->walk(Array)
#12 /domains/domainsmain/http/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogRule/Model/Observer.php(263): Mage_CatalogRule_Model_Rule->applyAll()
#13 [internal function]: Mage_CatalogRule_Model_Observer->dailyCatalogUpdate(Object(Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Schedule))
#14 /domains/domainsmain/http/app/code/community/Aoe/Scheduler/Model/Schedule.php(151): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#15 /domains/domainsmain/http/app/code/community/Aoe/Scheduler/Model/Schedule.php(510): Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Schedule->runNow(true)
#16 /domains/domainsmain/http/app/code/community/Aoe/Scheduler/Model/Observer.php(39): Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Schedule->process()
#17 /domains/domainsmain/http/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1358): Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Observer->dispatch(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#18 /domains/domainsmain/http/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1337): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Observer), 'dispatch', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#19 /domains/domainsmain/http/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('default', Array)
#20 /domains/domainsmain/http/cron.php(78): Mage::dispatchEvent('default')
#21 {main}

Next exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction, query was: DELETE FROM `catalogrule_product` WHERE (rule_id = '15')' in /domains/domainsmain/http/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:235
Stack trace:
#0 /domains/domainsmain/http/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /domains/domainsmain/http/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /domains/domainsmain/http/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /domains/domainsmain/http/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('DELETE FROM `ca...', Array)
#4 /domains/domainsmain/http/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(504): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('DELETE FROM `ca...', Array)
#5 /domains/domainsmain/http/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(664): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('DELETE FROM `ca...')
#6 /domains/domainsmain/http/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogRule/Model/Resource/Rule.php(164): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->delete('catalogrule_pro...', Array)
#7 /domains/domainsmain/http/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogRule/Model/Resource/Rule.php(344): Mage_CatalogRule_Model_Resource_Rule->cleanProductData('15')
#8 [internal function]: Mage_CatalogRule_Model_Resource_Rule->updateRuleProductData(Object(Mage_CatalogRule_Model_Rule))
#9 /domains/domainsmain/http/lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php(466): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#10 /domains/domainsmain/http/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogRule/Model/Rule.php(317): Varien_Data_Collection->walk(Array)
#11 /domains/domainsmain/http/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogRule/Model/Observer.php(263): Mage_CatalogRule_Model_Rule->applyAll()
#12 [internal function]: Mage_CatalogRule_Model_Observer->dailyCatalogUpdate(Object(Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Schedule))
#13 /domains/domainsmain/http/app/code/community/Aoe/Scheduler/Model/Schedule.php(151): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#14 /domains/domainsmain/http/app/code/community/Aoe/Scheduler/Model/Schedule.php(510): Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Schedule->runNow(true)
#15 /domains/domainsmain/http/app/code/community/Aoe/Scheduler/Model/Observer.php(39): Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Schedule->process()
#16 /domains/domainsmain/http/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1358): Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Observer->dispatch(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#17 /domains/domainsmain/http/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1337): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Observer), 'dispatch', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#18 /domains/domainsmain/http/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('default', Array)
#19 /domains/domainsmain/http/cron.php(78): Mage::dispatchEvent('default')
#20 {main}
```

This is what happens when I want to execute this rule, could anyone help me solve this?

Comment: seems like lot of rule and time out problem, you need to increase time for mysql conenction

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a lot of rule in magento admin and due to timeout problem, you are getting this issue. Please increase the value of 2 parameters on your server.

`innodb_lock_wait_timeout` and `lock_wait_timeout`

For more details please check this link-

https://www.polcode.com/en/the-lock-wait-timeout-exceeded-error-in-magento-find-and-solve-it/